# How to use the debugger in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for C++ coding on Ubuntu 18.04.

I found that for the debugging, I should always build an a.out file and then use the debugger. If I run the code directly by ctrl+alt+n then the code runs completely but it won't give me an a.out file.

Is there any way that I can automate this process?

I have also noticed that there is no build option available.

Here is the launch.json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: install Eclipse for C++ developement on your Ubuntu. You will have an IDE, a graphical GUI for debugging, graphical project configuration, ...

Comment: Please edit your question and add your JSON files you used to configure your workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create custom build+launch task for running your C++ code through a debugger.

Let's say we have this sample code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    vector<int> numbers{ 10, 20, 30 };
    for (int n : numbers)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

First, make sure to have [Microsoft's C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) installed.

Next, create a custom [build task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_build-helloworldcpp).
This tells VS Code how to **compile** your code.

1. Open the Command Palette
2. Select *Tasks: Configure Task*
3. Select *C/C++: g++: build active file*

   - You can other compilers that are available on your system
4. That would create or open an existing *.vscode/tasks.json* file
5. Configure it

   ```
   {
       "type": "shell",
       "label": "build-my-app",
       "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
       "args": [
           "-g",
           "-std=c++11",
           "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/test.cpp",
           "-o",
           "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/test.out"
       ],
       "options": {
           "cwd": "/usr/bin"
       },
       "problemMatcher": [
           "$gcc"
       ],
       "group": "build"
   }
   ```

   - Set `label` to uniquely name your custom task
   - Set the compile flags like `-g`, `-std=xxx`, `-l<lib>`, `-I<header>`
   - Set the output filename instead of *a.out*

Next, create a custom [launch task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_debug-helloworldcpp).
This tells VS Code how to run your code through the debugger.

1. Open the Command Palette
2. Select *Debug: Open launch.json*
3. That would create or open an existing *.vscode/launch.json* file
4. Configure it

   ```
   {
       "name": "run-my-app",
       "type": "cppdbg",
       "request": "launch",
       "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/test.out",
       "preLaunchTask": "build-my-app",
       "args": [],
       "stopAtEntry": false,
       "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
       "environment": [],
       "externalConsole": false,
       "MIMode": "lldb"
   }
   ```

   - Set `name` to uniquely name your launch task
   - Set `preLaunchTask` to the build task `label` you created earlier
   - Set `program` to the output filename you set in the build task

Finally, whenever you want to run your app, just open the Debug/Run panel and select your launch task from the dropdown (find the `name` you set in *launch.json*). Set your breakpoints then click the Play button.

[image]

[image]

You'll get the debugger controls for stepping through your code, the variables and call stack information, and the console output in the Debug Console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to compile using the the flag -g

Something like

g++ -g file.cpp

This command should generate an excutable and a directory that contains information that the debugger can read.

I am no sure if this is appropiate for VS debugger since I use gdb (gnu debugger) but maybe will work

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I want to automate it. I cannot always go to the terminal and run the source file.